# How to convert two json elements to one with name of the first one and value of the second one

Tags: java, json, gson

I was trying to make settings file and i got this result:

```
   [
      {
        "name": "Test1",
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "name": "Test2",
        "value": 1.7
      }
    ]
```

What i am trying to get is something like this:

```
{
    "Test1": true,
    "Test2": 1.7
}
```

As you can see, the second one is a whole lot better, and it is also easier to get data from this.
I am transforming the **Setting** Object into JSON, and the *name* and *value* variables are put into seperate elements.

Here's my code:

```
public class SettingsFile {
    public ArrayList<Setting> settings = new ArrayList<>();

    private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    private final String path;

    public SettingsFile(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public void save() {
        try {
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(path);
            gson.toJson(settings, fileWriter);
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And here is the **Setting** class:

```
public class Setting<type> {
    private type value;
    private String name;
    public Setting(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Setting<type> set(type value) {
        this.value = value;
        return this;
    }

    public type get() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map` instead of `Setting` class,

```
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> settings = new ArrayList<>();
```